# Javascript/JQuery - Controlling the iOS keypad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, touchstart, iphone-keypad

Based on my previous post where I attempt to fire off an event before the keypad opens on iOS, I am using the "touchstart" option to fire off an event.

[Fire Event before 'focus' kicks in / Fire Event before keyboard appears on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570852/fire-event-before-focus-kicks-in-fire-event-before-keyboard-appears-on-ios)

This works great, but when the device is slightly delayed the touchstart doesn't fire quick enough before the blur so the keyboard appears before the code is fired which is a major issue (we are working around the position: fixed;) issue.

My question is this:
Is there any way to control the keypad? Adding a timer or anything (even a code break) on the touchstart doesn't stop the keypad appearing on blur (when the touch is removed).

Thank you!